# Flutter, How to print the position of the widget in a list after onTap?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am dynamically adding card widget to a list and displaying the list in a screen using listView Builder, How do I get the index of the widget after `onTap`. For example if I tap on 4th card widget on the screen I should get the index of that widget.

Comment: you have index param inside  itemBuilder of Listview.Builder widget you can use that index  for particular card position which was pressed

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your actual code, but in general you shouldn't be adding the widgets themselves in the list, but only the information needed to build the widgets. That way you create the widget in the builder, where you have access to the index.

Alternatively, you wrap the widget with a `GestureDetector` or similar in the builder. Something like

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: ()=> print(index), //here you have access to it
      child: items[index]
    );
  })
```